Multistate Survival Models with Censored and Tidymodels
I am trying to use tidymodels' newish censored functionality to create a multistate survival model and am running into issues. I am seeing the below error when I try to fit my model. Normally this can be resolved by setting the id variable in teh coxph() function, but I can't get this to work with tidymodels.
Error in survival::coxph(formula = x ~ ., data = data, x = TRUE, model = TRUE) :
an id statement is required for multi-state models
Reproducible example below
library(tidyverse)
library(tidymodels)
library(censored)


df <- tibble(
  
  id = seq(1:1000),
  sex = sample(c("Male","Female"), 1000, replace = T),
  duration = rnorm(1000, mean = 75, sd = 7),
  outcome = sample(c("censor","Lost","Won"), 1000, replace = T)
  
) %>%
  mutate(
    outcome = factor(outcome)
  )



mod_df <- df %>%
   mutate(
     sale_surv = Surv(duration, outcome),
     .keep = "unused"
   )


set.seed(1988)

mod_split <- initial_split(mod_df)
mod_train <- training(mod_split)
mod_test <- testing(mod_split)

mod_rec <- recipe(sale_surv ~ sex, data = mod_train, id = id) 

mod_spec <- proportional_hazards() %>%
  set_mode("censored regression") %>%
  set_engine("survival") 

mod_wflow <- workflow() %>%
  add_recipe(mod_rec) %>%
  add_model(mod_spec)


mod_fit <- fit(mod_wflow, data = mod_train)



I can tell you how to do this but I encountered a bug for this specific function.
To do this, you give add_model() a value for the formula option. This gives it directly to the model formula at the last minute when fit() is called. It does not do any preprocessing (and let's the model handle it).
The bug is that dplyr thinks that we mean dplyr::id() (which we do not). Here, id is a special when it comes to formula. There actually is no id() function (in survival), but that's kind of a keyword that survival adds to the formula method (old school formulas ¯\(ツ)/¯.
I've filed an issue: https://github.com/tidymodels/workflows/issues/268
Here's a reprex that shows the failure:
library(tidyverse)
library(tidymodels)
library(censored)
#> Loading required package: survival

df <- tibble(
  sample_id = seq(1:1000),
  sex = sample(c("Male","Female"), 1000, replace = T),
  duration = rnorm(1000, mean = 75, sd = 7),
  outcome = sample(c("censor","Lost","Won"), 1000, replace = T)
  
) %>%
  mutate(
    outcome = factor(outcome)
  )

mod_df <- df %>%
  mutate(
    sale_surv = Surv(duration, outcome),
    .keep = "unused"
  )

set.seed(1988)

mod_split <- initial_split(mod_df)
mod_train <- training(mod_split)
mod_test <- testing(mod_split)

mod_rec <- recipe(sale_surv ~ sex, data = mod_train) # no `id` here 

mod_spec <- proportional_hazards() %>%
  set_mode("censored regression") %>%
  set_engine("survival") 

mod_wflow <- workflow() %>%
  add_recipe(mod_rec) %>%
  add_model(mod_spec, formula = sale_surv ~ sex + id(sample_id)) # add a formula here

mod_fit <- fit(mod_wflow, data = mod_train)
#> Error:
#> ! `id()` was deprecated in dplyr 0.5.0 and is now defunct.
#> ℹ Please use `vctrs::vec_group_id()` instead.


Thank you @topepo! I was spinning my wheels and planned to open up an issue, but wanted to get tidymodel expert eyes on it. Appreciate your work.
